# How to experiment with GPU programming on Linux+AMD/ATI card?

Tags: linux, gpu

I've recently acquired a laptop with an Intel i3 CPU and an AMD/ATI 6300 card, running Ubuntu 10.10.

How do I proceed in setting up a development environment that allows me to program the GPU? I assume I'll have to use OpenCL (CUDA is NVIDIA-only), but since I'm a novice with GPU programming, I'm asking the advice from more experienced programmers on the issue.

Answer (score 5):

To be able to use your graphics card to do GPUGP, the easiest way to learn is to use OpenCL.

In order to use it with your AMD card, you'll have to install the [**AMD APP SDK**](http://developer.amd.com/tools/heterogeneous-computing/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/). <s>On their download page they have a package that is compatible with Ubuntu 10.04, but ought to work OK on 10.10 also.</s>

UPDATE: [current version (as of Q4 2012) requires Ubuntu 11.04 or newer](http://developer.amd.com/tools/heterogeneous-computing/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/system-requirements/),

On the [documentation page](http://developer.amd.com/tools/heterogeneous-computing/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/documentation/) you can find tutorials.